# Flutter list UI is not updating when item is removed

Tags: flutter, list

I want my UI to automatically refresh when item deleted. Item is still there after the delete.

getItems() is for returning a frest list

futureBuilder() looks out for updates

StatefulBuilder() containing the Elevated Button to remove item from the list

```
 Future<List<Rung>> getItems() async {
      await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2));
    return _items; //Returns my list
  }
```

```
 return FutureBuilder(
        future: getItems(),
      
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Rung>> snapshot) {
          // builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
           
            return DefaultTabController(
```

```
...

return NotificationListener(
      child: SizedBox(
        child: Container(       
          child: ReorderableDragStartListener(
            index: index,
            child: InkWell(
          
                showDialog(
                  context: context,
                  builder: (BuildContext context) {
                    return Center(
                      child: SizedBox(                    
                        child: AlertDialog(
                          title: const Text("Edit task"),
                          content: StatefulBuilder(
                            builder: (BuildContext context,
                                void Function(void Function()) setState) {
                              return Column(
                                children: [
                                  
                                  const Text('Delete your task forever '),
                                  ElevatedButton(
                                    onPressed: () async {
                                     
                                      setState(() {
                                        _items.removeAt(index);                                     
                                        getItems(); //I was hoping this would update UI with fresh list minus deleted item
                                      });
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try do this?

```
onPressed: () { _items.removeAt(index); }
```

This should rebuild and show you new list. If that doesn't work try something like this:

```
onPressed: () { getItems(); }
```

Where getItems(); :

```
void getItems() {
  List<Rung> newList = _items.removeAt(index);
  setState(() {_list = newList;});
}
```

This code make newList without removed item and setState will rebuild state if _list will change. Let me know if it works for you.